# Вывести последнюю информацию из связанных таблиц в mysql по datetime

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Есть таблицы `mn` и `mn_status`.

`mn_status` связана с `mn` через поле `id_mn`,

`mn_status` содержит поле `dt` (`datetime`) и `info` (`text`).

Задача: вывести записи из таблицы `mn` с последними событиями содержащимися в `mn_status`, т.е. для каждой записи в таблице `mn` нужно выбрать последнее событие по `dt` и показать информацию из `info`.

Дату вывести получилось, но как вывести `info`, что-то туплю.

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.`name`, 
       u.`ip`, 
       u.`description`,
       ( SELECT `dt` 
         FROM mn_status 
         WHERE id_mn = ur.`id_mn` 
         ORDER BY `dt` DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS `last` 
FROM mn u 
left JOIN mn_status ur ON u.`id` = ur.`id_mn` 
WHERE public = 1 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Получи в подзапросе даты для всех, и уже это связывай со второй таблицей.

Comment: По сути я и так получаю даты для всех записей таблицы mn.

Comment: Да, но не в источнике данных, а в результирующем наборе. Где его дальнейшее использование невозможно.